# loading data to target based on condition

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have these 3 records coming from the flat file and want the below logic in place to load data to target.

```
Ref_no,status
100,A
100,B
200,B
```

if status is found - A, for any one of the ref_no. No data should get loaded for the ref_no

output should be like,

```
Ref_no,status
200,B
```

Can someone share some insights, on how this could be achieved through transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Of course possible.

1. Add a sorter and sort on Ref_no.
2. Then add a aggregator. set group by Ref_no. Add an output port like this

```
out_status_a = min( IIF(status='A','A','Z') -- this picks rows with status=A.
```

3. Joining aggregator and sorter using a joiner - join on Ref_no. pull out_status_a from aggregator.
4. Put a filter after joiner. Filer on out_status_a <>'A'.
   whole map will look like -

```
         |--> AGG->\
->SRT -->|--------->JNR -->FIL
```

Explanation -
Aggregator will stamp 'A' to all Ref_no in the table. Joiner will ensure if one row has 'A', all records have out_status_a =A for all the Ref_no.
You can use a filter instead of agg, but if you have dups, it will cause dups while joiner.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that, perhaps a bit less resource consuming is to use an `Expression Transformation` add an integer column, say

```
is_A_found = IIF(status='B', 1, 0)
```

Next, use `Aggregator` to group by `Ref_no` and calculate

```
max_status = MAX(is_A_found)
```

Then just filter with the condition

```
max_status = 0
```

This will leave only the rows where for the given `Ref_no` there was no `A` status. Whole flow would be straightforward with just one transformation using cache:

```
Src->SQ->Exp_is_A_found->Agg->Flt->Tgt
```